# Project Euler - Smallest multiple

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, programming-challenge

Here's [Problem 5 - Smallest multiple](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5)

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

How can I improve this code? How to make it faster? Is there a better/faster solution?

```
#include <iostream>

bool calculate(int number, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return (number % n != 0) ? false : calculate(number,n-1);
}

int main() {
    int number = 20;
    int result = number;
    while (!calculate(result, number)) {
        result += number;
    }
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You arrive at the answer by counting 20 at a time.  That's 11639628 iterations of the main loop — and many recursive calls to `calculate()`.

A more efficient and satisfying approach would be to use the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) to compute LCMs.

Note that an `int` is not guaranteed to be large enough to hold the result.  I suggest using `long` everywhere.

```
#include <iostream>

long gcd(long a, long b) {
    while (b) {
        int prevB = b;
        b = a % b;
        a = prevB;
    }
    return a;
}

long lcm(long a, long b) {
    return a * (b / gcd(a, b));
}

int main() {
    long result = 20;
    for (long number = result - 1; number > 1; --number) {
        result = lcm(result, number);
    }
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You posted two answers? Why not merge them :)

Comment: Because the two answers are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

`calculate()` is not at all an informative name.  My suggestion for the name would be `isMultipleOfRange()`.  Personally, I find it easier to understand if written non-recursively, but that's a matter of opinion.

```
bool isMultipleOfRange(int number, int n) {
    while (n > 0) {
        if (number % n-- != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```