# Project Euler Problem #5 Solution in C++

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

> ### [Project Euler #5: Smallest multiple](https://projecteuler.net/problem=5)
>
> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>
> What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?"

And I'm wondering if my code to solve this problem is good and if there are ways to make it better.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
int smallestMultiple = 40;
int i = 10;

while (i<20){
    if (smallestMultiple%i == 0){
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    else{
        i = 10;
        smallestMultiple += 20;
    }
    }
std::cout << smallestMultiple;
}
```

Comment: There are far more efficient ways to get the result. I would suggest to have a look at existing Q&A's about the same problem, such as https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/80500/35991.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### First reviewing the code itself:

1. First, fix the indentation, and insert an empty line before your `main()`. Proper formatting is a most basic step allowing easier comprehension.
2. `"stdafx.h"` is part of the MSVC-support for pre-compiled headers. Your project is so small it cannot really take advantage of that anyway, so it's just a wart.
3. Use the right loop for the job. A `for`-loop seems to fit better, as you have *init* (with declaration), *condition*, *next*, and *body*.
4. Don't use `contine` where it has no effect, nor clarifies intent.
5. In general, `int` is too small for your result. Luckily(?), on Windows it's 32 bit, which should suffice.
6. Put the calculation into its own function for re-use.
7. Don't forget to output a newline at the end, it's expected and omitting it might have interesting effects.

#### And then the algorithm:

Testing every 20<sup>th</sup> number whether it's the target is supremely inefficient. Even using steps of 2520 instead isn't that much better.
Consider constructing the result instead:

1. *r* = 1
2. For *i* = 2 to the limit

   - If *i* does not divide *r*

     - Multiply *r* by the highest integer-power of *i* not exceeding the limit.

Keeping in mind that Project Euler is not really for brute-force or straight-up coding, but figuring out an intelligent approach for manually calculating things:

1. 2520 is the least common multiple of the numbers 1 through 10.
2. Go through 11 to 20, and figure out whether you need an additional factor.
   Observation: 4 times the number itself (it's prime), once the fourth root.
3. That's easily put into a calculator, for the result 232792560.

#### Putting it all together:

```
#include <iostream>

static unsigned long lcm_until(unsigned n) noexcept {
    auto r = 1UL;
    for (auto i = 2UL; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (r % i) { // i is prime
            auto x = i;
            while (x * i <= n)
                x *= i;
            r *= x;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << lcm_until(20) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Much better code - it does break down without warning after `n=115` on this system with 64-bit `unsigned long` (or after `n=159` with 128-bit `unsigned long`).  Of course, the original code would take years to get to those values...

Answer (score 10):

## Code Review

Despite its name, `"stdafx.h"` isn't a standard header.  It doesn't seem to be needed, as the code compiles and runs without it.

Your indentation is off - perhaps that's a result of how you inserted the code into the question?

The `continue` is redundant - there's no more code within the loop after the `if`/`else`, so it can be omitted.

The code assumes that a result will be found before `int` overflows.  Remember that `INT_MAX` may be as small as 32767; perhaps `unsigned long` may be a better choice, or one of the fixed-width types specified in `<cstdint>`, perhaps?

Your loop structure would be clearer if you separate out the test from incrementing smallest multiple.  That could look something like this (still using `int` as our type):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

static bool is_multiple_of_all(int n, int max)
{
    for (int i = 10;  i <= max;  ++i) {
        if (n % i != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    const int target = 20;
    for (int candidate = 2 * target;
         candidate <= INT_MAX - target;
         candidate += target)
    {
        if (is_multiple_of_all(candidate, target)) {
            std::cout << candidate;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // not found
    return 1;
}
```

## Algorithm

Project Euler problems tend to exercise your mathematical reasoning.  You're expected to find better methods than brute force search to find the solution.  (Hint: think about prime factors).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this, is to use the [`std::lcm(m, n)` (c++17)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm) function.  Start with 2520 and 11:

```
#include <numeric>
using std::lcm;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
ull solve()
{
    static const int limit = 20;
    static int current = 11;
    static ull answer = 2520;
    if (current > limit)
    {
        return answer;
    }
    answer = lcm(answer, current++);
    return solve();
}
```

Comment: That appears to be a single-use function.  I wouldn't advise that, because it makes it hard to generalise to one that accepts an argument.  Besides, it's much clearer in iterative form:  `for (auto current = 2u;  current <= limit;  ++current)
        answer = std::lcm(answer, current++);`.  Do note that `std::lcm()` gives wrong results from only `limit==86`, so we have less range when we use this function.

Comment: `static` state to avoid direct Iteration? Evil. Also, an `int` is potentially too small. And I'm not sure memoizing the solution is a good idea at all. Also, a using-declaration for a function used once, a typedef better replaced by more generous use of `auto`, and an aversion to empty lines? hm...